# How can I execute a function using a variable name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```js
$(function(){
  function myfunc(){
    alert("executed");
  }
  
  var function_name = "myfunc";
  window[function_name]();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, that function is not defined. Why? And how can I make it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is not defined in the global scope so it’s not a member of the window object.

You can attach the function to the window object like this.

```
$(function(){
  window.myfunc = function(){
    alert("executed");
  };

  var function_name = "myfunc";
  window[function_name]();
})
```

Comment: While technically correct. Using Global scope is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

It works only for global functions, because the scope is identically with the `window` object.

You could assing a function to a wanted property of the `window` object, just as to any other object.

```js
function myfunc(){
    alert("executed");
}

$(function(){
    var function_name = "myfunc";
    window[function_name]();
    window.foo = _ => console.log('foo');
    window.foo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Right. Thank you .. Isn't there an approach to define a function in global scope inside `$(function(){ ... })` ?

Answer (score 0):

While the direct answer to your question is that your function wasn't defined as a Global and so, attempting to call it as a property of `window` fails, putting your function into Global scope is not really a good answer.

Instead, make the function a method of a user-defined object (that can be put into any scope you like) and call the function as a property of that object:

```js
// Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)
// that keeps all of its contents out of the Global scope
(function(){

  let functionHolder = {
    someFunction : function(){ console.log("You did it!"); }
  };

  // Set up a variable that has the same name as the function
  let funcName = "someFunction";

  // Call the function via the object
  functionHolder[funcName]();

})()
```